# Google Maps Polyline click does not fire PolyMouseEvent

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the index of the edge in the path of a polyline as it is written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolyMouseEvent).  However, I get undefined values whenever I trigger the click event on the polyline.

Here is my code: edge, path and vertex are all undefined

```
route = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: polyLineArray,
strokeColor: "#FF0000",
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 5,
clickable: true,
editable: false
});
    
google.maps.event.addListener(route, 'click', function(evt) {           
  console.log("route click1: " + evt.edge);
  console.log("route click2: " + evt.path);
  console.log("route click2: " + evt.vertex);
  console.log("route click3: " + evt);
  for(var property in evt) {
   console.log("route click4: " + property + " - " + evt[property]);
  }
```

}
});

Am I missing something here? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

I see the same results on [my test case](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_arc_click.html)

Testing further, looks like they are available on "editiable" polylines, the vertex is true if you click on on of the white squares, the path is true if you edit the polyline and click on one of the "new" vertices".
[test case with editable polyline](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_arc_editable_click.html)

Looking closer at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolyMouseEvent), it is pretty clear it just applies to editable polylines/polygons:

```
google.maps.PolyMouseEvent object
This object is returned from mouse events on polylines and polygons.

This object extends MouseEvent.
Properties
Properties | Type   | Description
edge       | number | The index of the edge within the path beneath the cursor when 
                    | the event occurred, if the event occurred on a mid-point on an 
                    | editable polygon.
path       | number | The index of the path beneath the cursor when the event 
                    | occurred, if the event occurred on a vertex and the polygon
                    | is editable. Otherwise undefined.
vertex     | number | The index of the vertex beneath the cursor when the event 
                    | occurred, if the event occurred on a vertex and the polyline or 
                    | polygon is editable. If the event does not occur on a vertex, 
                    | the value is undefined.
```

More information.  Clicking on the little white squares (the "edit handles") gives either a vertex # or an edge number, haven't found a way to make the path anything but undefined, but that may be because so far I have only played with polylines.