# Accessing child nodes of polyline in Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

[Example Code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FahVc/)

Hi,

I would like to "access" the child nodes (squares) of a polyline in Google Maps v3. By access I mean delete this point from the polyline and auto reconnect the neighbors. Are there event listeners for "accessing" the nodes? I cannot find anything.

Thank you for you help!

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**Found the solution** ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FahVc/)):

```
var deleteNode = function(mev) {
  if (mev.vertex != null) {
    my_poly.getPath().removeAt(mev.vertex);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addListener(my_poly, 'rightclick', deleteNode);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer to this question for events available on editable polylines:

[Google Maps Polyline click does not fire PolyMouseEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060327/google-maps-polyline-click-does-not-fire-polymouseevent/12060897#12060897)

Answer (score 0):

**Found the solution** ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FahVc/)):

```
var deleteNode = function(mev) {
  if (mev.vertex != null) {
    my_poly.getPath().removeAt(mev.vertex);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addListener(my_poly, 'rightclick', deleteNode);
```

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) :)